# Include inner item when return JSon

Tags: c#, json, odata

I have an Employee class, taken from a database. In that Employee class, I want to add a Manager object, which is also an Employee, based on the managerCode that is in the Employee database. See below for the class.

The managerCode is not defined as a key, . I don’t need recursion, i.e. I don’t need the Manager’s manager, etc. Just one level, the Employee and his manager.

Using .NET 4.5, c#, OData v4

I am using OData to send back the Employee, but the Manager part isn’t added in the response, even if it’s there in the object I try to send.

What am I missing? Something in the WebApiConfig?

Thanks

Employee class, first 4 fields are directly taken from database.

```
Class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string employeeCode { get; set; }
    public string employeeName { get; set; }
    public string managerCode { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Employee Manager { get; set; }
}
```

Controller class. *GetEmployeeById(id)* will get Employee(s) with their Manager.

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
[ODataRoute("employeeById(id={id})")]
public IHttpActionResult employeeById([FromODataUri]int id)
{
    var sets = dbContext.GetEmployeeById(id);
    if (!sets.Any())
        return NotFound();
    return this.CreateOKHttpActionResult(sets);
}
```

WebApiConfig

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "odata",GetEdmModel(), 
    new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
    config.EnsureInitialized();
}

private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.Namespace = "employee_odata";
    builder.ContainerName = "employee_odataContainer";
    builder.EntitySet<Employee>("Employee");
    builder.EnableLowerCamelCase();

    var unboundGetEmployee = builder.Function("employeeById");
    unboundGetEmployee.Returns<Employee>();
    unboundGetEmployee.Parameter<int>("id");
    unboundGetEmployee.Namespace = "employee_odata.Functions";

    return builder.GetEdmModel();

}
```

**SOLUTION**

Remove `unboundGetEmployee` from WebApiConfig (not  needed).

Make Manager item in Employee class virtual, without the `[NotMapped]`:

```
public virtual Manager Manager { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
[EnableQuery]
[ODataRoute("Employee({id})")]
public IHttpActionResult employeeById([FromODataUri]int id)
{
    //handle data return normally...
    //I have to detect $expand=Manager, to fetch the actual Manager object.
    //otherwise it's null (not linked with primary key)
}
```

With these fee changes, $expand is working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add $expand to show navigation property, like

```
localhost\odata\employee_odata.Functions.employeeById(id=1)?$expand=Manager
```

And for get employee by Id, I suggest you to use this method in controller:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
{
    var sets = dbContext.GetEmployeeById(id);
    if (!sets.Any())
        return NotFound();
    return this.CreateOKHttpActionResult(sets);
}
```

Then request like `localhost\odata\Employee(1)` can route to that method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestion for the Get(). However, $expand=Manager doesn't work, it gives me _«Could not find a property named 'Manager' on type 'Models.Employee'»_. Any idea?

Comment: Solved it. See update above. It was a combination of a few little things.